# RadioButtons in ListBox don't work correctly using with Theme

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, radio-button, themes

I want to use a `RadioButtonList` and want to check one of the `RadioButtonList` at initial display.

But the radioButtons in `ListBox` doesn't work correctly using with theme.

I set "Radio1" toSelectedItem1 property in the constructor of ViewModel. but Radio1 doesn't be checked at initial display. If I click Radio2 and click Radio1, Radio1 is checked correctly.

If I remove the theme from app.xaml, Radio1 is checked correctly at the initial display. I downloaded the theme file from http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/14962 .

You can download the project by https://github.com/koty/RadioButtonListTest.

The xaml is:

```xml
<Window x:Class="RadioButtonListTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RadioButtonListTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RBItems1}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem1}">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <RadioButton Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                    IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsSelected}" Foreground="Black"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

The ViewModel is:

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace RadioButtonListTest
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : DependencyObject
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            this.RBItems1 = new[] { "Radio1", "Radio2" };
            this.SelectedItem1 = "Radio1";
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RBItems1Property
            = DependencyProperty.Register("RBItems1",
                                          typeof (string[]),
                                          typeof (MainWindowViewModel),
                                          new PropertyMetadata(default(string[])));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItem1Property
            = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem1",
                                          typeof (string),
                                          typeof (MainWindowViewModel),
                                          new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

        public string[] RBItems1
        {
            get { return (string[]) GetValue(RBItems1Property); }
            set { SetValue(RBItems1Property, value); }
        }

        public string SelectedItem1
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(SelectedItem1Property); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedItem1Property, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

And the app.xaml is:

```xml
<Application x:Class="RadioButtonListTest.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes\ShinyBlue\Theme.xaml"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: This is entirely wrong approach of MVVM , you are inheriting VM from DependencyObject. You should Create UserControl instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change a little code in **ShinyBlue.xaml**.

In the original code there was not one trigger.

Find `RadioButtonTemplate` and change it with this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="CheckedFalse">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="CheckedTrue">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOn">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2000000" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOff">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="PressedOn">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2000000" Value="0.6"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="PressedOff">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2000000" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <Grid Width="16" Height="16">
                                <Ellipse Height="14"
                       Margin="1"
                       x:Name="Background"
                       Width="14"
                       Fill="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
                       Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                       StrokeThickness="2"/>
                                <Ellipse Height="12"
                       x:Name="BackgroundOverlay"
                       Width="12"
                       Opacity="0"
                       Fill="{StaticResource HoverBrush}"
                       Stroke="#00000000"
                       Margin="2,2,2,2"
                       StrokeThickness="0"/>
                                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      Width="6"
                      Height="6"
                      CornerRadius="1,1,1,1"
                      BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
                      Background="#FFFFFFFF"
                      x:Name="CheckIcon"
                      BorderBrush="{StaticResource CheckIconBrush}"
                      Opacity="0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </BulletDecorator>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedFalse}" x:Name="CheckedFalse_BeginStoryboard"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedTrue}"/>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedTrue}" x:Name="CheckedTrue_BeginStoryboard"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedFalse}"/>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOn}"/>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOff}"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource PressedOn}"/>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource PressedOff}"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBorderBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Using your code, the RadioButtons worked correctly. thank you so much!